# Copying data from Source Workbook to my current workbook under condition to match defined name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to run the code that will extract the data from some another source Workbook (saved on my PC) to my current Workbook that I need to update. 
This means that I need to work with 2 Workbooks (My current Workbook and another Source Workbook), but the Source Workbook should not be opened but only referenced by its path name so as to copy data from it.
I have found similar topics and everything would work fine except the fact that I need a condition under which the data can be copied from the another Workbook to my current one.

I have a Defined name in my current workbook and I want the code to copy the data from another Source workbook only if the Defined name (defined in current workbook) can be found in certain column of the Source workbook (here no names are defined). To make it more horrible, the values in this specific column of Source Workbook that need to match Defined Name in my current workbook, must also align only according to the first 18 characters on the left, and the rest can be different. So, if in this specific column of the Source Workbook, the first 18 characters are not the same as my Defined Name in my current Workbook, the data should not be copied. The sheet in my current Workbook where I want the data to be pasted is called 'Test'. Whereas, the Source Workbook has the random name every time I will copy the data from it, and it has only one standard Sheet called 'Sheet1' from where the data are to be copied (that's why I want it to be called by its path name only).

I would be very grateful for help in regards to writing this condition, the terms of opening the Source Workbook (without actual opening it) and coping data in my current Workbook works fine, but I am mixing the condition.

Below is the code I am working with (After the statement 'Else' everything works fine):

```
Sub Copy_Data()

    Dim ActiveArray As Variant
    Dim SourceWBpath As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    endRow = 1003
    Const l_MyDefinedName As String = "MyDefinedName"
    Const s_ColumnToMatch As String = "N:N"   'The column in Source Workbook to be match with My defined name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ActiveArray = ActiveWorkbook
    Set SourceWBpath = Worksheets("Test").Range("E1")      'Cell with path to the Source Workbook
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(SourceWBpath)
    Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

 '**************************Copy Workbook content to this sheet****************************************************
    For i = 5 To endRow
        With SourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(s_ColumnToMatch)
            Dim strCellValue As String: strCellValue.Value2  'This is supposed to look up the values in SOurce WOrkbook in column N:N and match with Mydefined Name
                If SourceWBpath= "" And Left(strCellValue, Len(Range("MyDefinedName").Value2)) <> MyWorkbook.Range("MyDefinedName").Value2 Then

                    Else
                    Workbooks.Open SourceWBpath, local:=True
                    Range("A2:Y1900").Copy
                    ActiveArray.Sheets("Test").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
                End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

The more, I know that one thing that is missing in the code for sure is declaring some another variable e.g. i2 that will define that 'strCellValue' should match only according to 18 first characters on the left. I presume that it should be something like that:

```
i2 = InStr(1, strCellValue, Chr(18))
```

The problem is that I am not sure where it should be placed in the condition.

I will be very grateful for some tips.

Comment: Will your source workbook be the only file in a given path? Or if not, does it have any name pattern? You need to find the file using Dir function, then open it using the exact name/path.

Comment: Your post is way to long, you should break it down to the most important things and just enough to be able to understand your problem, its not necessary to describe the whole background. If you just want to match the first 18 characters use  the `left` function as you already did. like `if left(name, 18) = left(strCellValue, 18)`

Comment: @brainac: The source workbook is the only file in the path. But this works all fine. If I do not declare condition, the code is working fine as it opens (indirectly) my Source Workbook by referring to Worksheets("Test").Range("E1") . In E1 cell, I am storing the path name. But this is fine. The problem is with declaring the condition, the part after line of stars. After 'Else' the code is also working fine.

Comment: @UGP: Hmm, I was considering cutting the content, but I had experience when the content was actually to brief and then, you need add information as people are not sure what the story is about. But I admit that it went out little to extensive. Regarding the left function: I have the problem here as well, because after declaring 'strCellValue' variable, I get the error of invalid qualifier.

Comment: You define `strCellValue as string`, then you say `strCellValue.value2`, which makes no sense, because its a string and `value2` is a range property and also even if it is defined as range, it has no reference to any cell at all.

Comment: @Dozens It's still unclear what you exactly need. What is `ActualsBU` and why do you compare it to empty string? Why do you iterate over 1000 rows, but never refer them?

Comment: @brainac: I am sorry for that. I have just edited that. It was supposed to be SourceWBpath. I iterate over 1000 rows because I don't know how much data will be in Source Workbook. And I want to compare all possible values that are in the ColumnToMatch  with my defined name

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
Dim rngFound as Range
On Error Resume Next
set rngFound = SourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(s_ColumnToMatch).Find(What:=l_myDefinedName & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
ON error goto 0
If Not rngFound IS Nothing then
rngfound.currentRegion.Copy ActiveArray.Sheets("Test").Range("A5")
End If
```

I assumed your source file data can be selected with CurrentRegion. If not, you can stick to your range selection, but I would go with `rngFound.Parent.Range("A2:Y1900").Copy`